# Can't catch \InvalidArgumentException in Symfony2 Controller

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I found many questions about catching exceptions in Symfony2 and none of the answers seem to apply to my situation.

I am trying to call `$this->forward()` in my controller and it throws an `\InvalidArgumentException` which I can't catch..  I just get the 500 error page instead.

```
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

My attempt at catching this exception:

```
try {
    $response = $this->forward('FooBundle:Foo:bar', ['foo' => 'bar']);
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
    error_log($ex->getMessage());
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    // this doesn't work either
}
```

This exception is being thrown by Symfony in `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver` on line 65:

```
throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Controller "%s" for URI "%s" is not callable.', get_class($controller), $request->getPathInfo()));
```

This appears to be an SPL exception.  And it *appears* as though I were catching it properly.  So what is missing?

**Note:** This is in my dev environment if that has anything to do with it.

---

Interestingly enough, putting *this* in my controller **does work**:

```
try {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Fake Exception');
} catch (\InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't even notice that the 500 error was the actual response from the call to `forward()`.  Perhaps the Q should be deleted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the 500 error was the response body of the forward - which technically *was* working.  The call to `$this->forward()` was not the issue, the issue was I was displaying the response body *without checking it first*.

Fixed it by doing this:

```
$response = $this->forward('FooBundle:Foo:bar', ['foo' => 'bar']);
$content  = (500 !== $response->getStatusCode()) 
    ? $response->getContent()
    : '';

return new Response($content);
```

**Note:** the `try {} catch (\Exception $e) {}` was completely unnecessary and actually pointless for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$response = $this->forward('FooBundle:Foo:bar');
```

I think this is correct unless your controller requires parameters, then you put the parameters in the array. Can you please try it? I'm not certain that will resolve the issue though.

Comment: There are params, I just didn't include them in my example code above.  That is not the issue though.  But thanks anyway!